# How can I read entries from a csv to edit an XML

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, xml

I'm working on an automated sync of my ADuser. I need to edit an xml file to do so but the source of this edit would be a csv file resulting of a get-aduser

I need to change the mail adress to make a foreach in powershell, the foreach target being the mail addresses in the csv.

so for now I have my csv with email addresses etc... and my config file sync.exe.cfg

The idea would be, after importing the CSV,

`foreach %USER% in file.csv
 Read Emailaddress
     load sync.exe.cfg 
     IN sync.exe.cfg
     "edit line usertosync=mail@blop.com with mail in cache"
     CALL sync.exe`

that or I could edit the mail part in the cfg with a variable and do the foreach on it without needing to alter the file. Just rewriting the variable outside the cfg.

---

Thanks for your time

Comment: Show us an example of as much of your code as you have, foreach etc. Write pseudo-code for the commands that you don't know how to write.

Comment: My whole idea is, in a script, to extract my user's list, use that list to run the exe on each of them. Perhaps later add a trigger on the server to start the script.

Comment: All of what you have identified, there are samples in the PowerShell help files on your system and on the MS docs sites for each. As well as all over the web. Look at the help files/examples regarding reading text file using Get-Content, or Import-Csv, as well as about ForLoop, Start-Process and Select-String.